# Unable to locate nCino element through Selenium in Salesforce

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, salesforce

I am using nCino application (build on Salesforce) for my project. nCino is a framework built on Salesforce application and called in a .

I am trying to automate functional flows in nCino UI through Selenium Java in Chrome browser (tried in Firefox too)

**Issue 1: Switch to iframe and click on element**
Refer to iframe code below

[image: iframe Source code]

Console error:

[image: CORS policy error in console]

Selenium Code Snippet to switch to iframe and click element inside element:

```js
package nCInoAutomation;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Parameters.FIREDRIVER);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Parameters.CHROMEDRIVER);
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
  //  chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); 
    WebDriver driver = new  ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    
    driver.get(Parameters.APPURL);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement formElement = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form"));
    formElement.findElement(By.id(Parameters.UNAME_XPATH)).sendKeys(Parameters.UNAME);
    formElement.findElement(By.id(Parameters.PWD_XPATH)).sendKeys(Parameters.PWD);
    formElement.findElement(By.id(Parameters.ENTER_XPATH)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    System.out.println("Wait Over");
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(2));
    
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println(list.size());
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement ele = list.get(2);
    
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", ele);  
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");

    System.out.println("********Switched to the iframe*******");
   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ncSecondaryNavigation']//span[text()='Loan'])[2]")));
    System.out.println("Clicked");
 
    
 }
}

It says that it has switched to iframe but doesnt look like so.
```

**Issue 2: Unable to locate element**
Also, iframe contains most of the angular js elements hence Unable to identify elements. See screenshot below:

[image: Source code of the page]

Application looks somewhat like below:

[image: Application Screenshot]

Can you please help me automate below:
1. Switch to iframe once landed on Salesforcw screen.
2. Navigate to 'Collateral' screen by clicking on the link.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's generally advised to limit number of questions in original question to just one.

Comment: Thanks and I agree, Both question are relevant to each other hence clubbed in one :)

Comment: Does it switch to the correct iframe? How many iframe are there?

Comment: I really doubt that it does. But I have passed correct details to switch to iframe. Just to double sure that, I highlight the iframe I am trying to switch to.